# Spring Boot logging before app starts on external Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm trying to do some logging whenever a Spring Boot app is about to start.

Currently I have a Class that implements `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` and I'm registering it as a Listener in the main function of the `SpringBootApplication`.

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final Logger appLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("INIT");
        appLogger.info("Initializing");

        SpringApplication sa = new SpringApplication();
        sa.addListeners(new InitializationLogger());
        sa.setSources(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(Application.class)));
        sa.run(args);

        appLogger.info("--Application Started--");
    }
}
```

InitializationLogger.java

```
public class InitializationLogger implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
    private static final Logger appLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitializationLogger.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getClass());
        appLogger.info(this.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I run the app through Intellij's SpringBoot runner or the command line as a fat jar, it works perfectly fine, but when I deploy it to an external Tomcat, these logs do not show up (all other app logs work fine).

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you check on the tomcat log ?

Comment: @PrabinPaudel Yes, no logs there as well

Comment: for me as well! it does not even call it! it goes to spring jpa initialization first and it fails because I add the required properties in this listener!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do this?

Overriding [SpringBootServletInitializer.configure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html#configure-org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder-), Something like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final Logger appLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    // for JAR deploy:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = configureSpringBuilder(new SpringApplicationBuilder());
        builder.application().run(args);
        appLogger.info("--Application Started--");
    }

    // for WAR deploy:
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return super.configure(configureSpringBuilder(builder));
    }

    // Common:
    private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureSpringBuilder(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        System.out.println("INIT");
        appLogger.info("Initializing");

        builder.application().addListeners(new InitializationLogger());
        builder.application().setSources(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(Application.class)));

        return builder;
    }
}
```

### References:

1. [Class SpringBootServletInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html)

   > To configure the application either override the configure(SpringApplicationBuilder) method (...)
2. [Tutorial: Use Spring Boot to Build and Deploy WAR Files - Setting Up a Servlet](https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-spring-boot-war-files#setting-up-a-servlet)

   > To set the app up as a servlet we extend the main class with SpringBootServletInitializer and override the configure method using SpringApplicationBuilder.
3. [Deploying Spring Boot Applications - What about the Java EE Application Server?](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server)

   > Modify your Application entry-point class thusly (...)